# How do i sign into a website using username/password from XCode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, webview

I'm pretty much new into Objective-c programing , and my knowledge of PHP is almost nothing.
Anyway, I'm trying to do a login screen in my App which has 2 text fields for username and password, and a button which suppose to enter the username/password into a website sign in page , and connect to the account.
I'm not sure if I'm on the right way but here is a sample of the code i made:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *content = @"username=blabla&password=123456";
    NSData *data=[content dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postlenght=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://roadster.co.il/forums/ucp.php?mode=login"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postlenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSURLResponse *response=nil;
    NSData *result=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    [webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

As you can see the website I'm trying to log into is 
http://roadster.co.il/forums/ucp.php?mode=login
I'm sorry but the website is in Hebrew but it not the matter. can you please tell me why i don't manage to sign in using this code? (tried with the real password/username)

Comment: If your knowledge of PHP is almost nothing, you might want to post the login code, but I'd be careful about how you go about this. Many security holes right off the bat

Comment: This line: `[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];` has a mistake, there should be "Content-Type" instead of "Content-Length". Can that be the problem?

Comment: I Changed it to "Content-Type" but still , the web view just loads the website at the login page, it doesn't show me that I'm logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to make the request twice.

```
NSError *error=nil;
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *result=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

[webview loadRequest:request];
```

Both `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` and `-loadRequest:` send the request to the server. You only want to do one or the other. Either, remove the first three lines of code, or use `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:` to load the result into web view.

```
NSString *HTMLString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[webview loadHTMLString:HTMLString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://roadster.co.il/forums/ucp.php?mode=login"]];
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the loadHTMLString, it seems to get closer to the solution and yet it didn't work it still loads the empty log in page.  as it seems I gave my information to the php - "username=blabla&password=123456", but I didn't call anywhere to try to log in. I mean is there a way to call the Login button function? I think that is what I'm missing (correct me if you think else)

Comment: @Adi: That's what sending the request—whether by sending it synchronously, sending it asynchronously, or making the WebView do it—does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "http://roadster.co.il/forums/ucp.php?mode=login" is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag.